# Is elastane (also known as spandex or lyrca) a halal material?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

Is elastane a halal material?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandex) describes it as:

> Spandex, Lycra or elastane is a synthetic fiber known for its exceptional elasticity. It is stronger and more durable than natural rubber. It is a polyether-polyurea copolymer that was invented in 1958 by chemist Joseph Shivers at DuPont's Benger Laboratory in Waynesboro, Virginia. When introduced in 1962, it revolutionized many areas of the clothing industry.

I've been trying to look for this but I can't really understand what it's made from.

Answer (score 1):

wasalam,

Elastane is another term for Spandex, it is made from synthetic polyster-polyurethane polymer.  It is man-made and has no haraam materials.